# how to set a 404 page in spring mvc by javaConfig

Tags: java, spring-mvc

first,i set the `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFo‌​und`,so make it can throw a exception

```
    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        super.customizeRegistration(registration);
        logger.info("正在注册服务...");
        registration.setInitParameter("enableLoggingRequestDetails", "true");
        registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFo‌​und","true");
    }
```

then, i write a `ControllerAdvice` and use a `ExceptionHandler` to handle the Exception ,but it doesn't work.
so how should i do.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorPageHandler {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionHandler.class);
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String error404(NoHandlerFoundException ex){
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex.getCause());
        return "404";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share you code on github ?